# PowerShell: Update Scheduled Task username and password?

Tags: powershell, scheduled-tasks

I'm looking for a way to update the credentials on existing scheduled tasks on machines.

- Schtasks doesn't work for AT created scheduled tasks
- Win32_ScheduledJob only works for AT created jobs
- Schedule.Service COM object - not sure

It appears that I can use RegisterTask and RegisterTaskDefinition to CREATE scheduled tasks but I'm not clear if I can update the existing credentials with those methods.  Please advise.  Thx.

Comment: For task scheduler 1.0 or 2.0?

Comment: Why are you still using AT style tasks? Is there an OS limitation here?

Comment: it's not that I'm particularly using AT to schedule tasks but i can't guarantee third-party vendors aren't.  the point is to use a method that is the *best* way to get all possible scheduled tasks.

Comment: and whatever task scheduler is in vista and beyond.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend having a look at the managed TaskScheduler API, which is a .NET wrapper for the TaskScheduler COM API. It's an open-source project available on CodePlex.

http://taskscheduler.codeplex.com/

The project author has this to say about updating passwords:

> If you are trying to create a task using the credentials of the
>   current user and you only want it to run when that user is logged in,
>   you need to call the RegisterTaskDefinition method as in the end of
>   the Complex example with the InteractiveToken parameter. If you need
>   to create as another specific user, then use that same method, but
>   supply the username, password, and set the TaskLogonType to
>   InteractiveTokenOrPassword or Password. There are some triggers that
>   are specific to a user, like the LogonTrigger where you can also
>   supply a user credential.

The appropriate overload for `RegisterTaskDefinition` is defined in TaskFolder.cs.

http://taskscheduler.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/75611#19440

```
public Task RegisterTaskDefinition(string Path, TaskDefinition definition
   , TaskCreation createType, string UserId, string password = null
   , TaskLogonType LogonType = TaskLogonType.S4U, string sddl = null)
```

Comment: i really don't want to use a third-party code; especially since it's not powershell but the block quote you posted from the project seems to elude to the pieces of of the Schedule.Service COM object I probably need to use.

Comment: You can easily load this .NET library into PowerShell. But yes, as you mentioned, you can probably figure out the COM methods from the source code of that project.

Comment: well it's not so much that i couldn't use the code natively since powershell can invoke other languages naturally written.  the problem is that i'm trying to stay away from as many dependencies as possible and even though the COM object is really a dependency, it ships with the OS instead of having to provide the third party code with the PoSh file.

Comment: This blog post looks like it may work for you http://windowsitpro.com/scripting/updating-scheduled-tasks-credentials.

Answer (score 2):

I had this task come up recently. I know this post is old but wanted to put this script somewhere for people to find hopefully help them. This is pure power shell so no extra setup required. I had tried using the Set-ScheduledTask but had issues setting domain user. I ended up using schtasks instead. You may need to run this script as administrator.

```
$domainUsername = "domain\user"
$password= "somePassword"
 
$tasks = Get-ScheduledTask | Where-Object { $_.Principal.UserId -eq $domainUsername }

foreach ($task in $tasks) {
    $myTask = $task.TaskPath+$task.TaskName
    echo changing $myTask
    schtasks /change /s $env:COMPUTERNAME /tn $myTask  /ru $domainUsername /rp $password
}
```

Here is another example of how to push out to multiple servers. THe sessionCredentials are the credentials used to connect to the servers the domain user and new password are the name and password to be set to the tasks

```
$sessionCredentials = Get-Credential

$taskDomainUsername = "DOMAIN\SOMEACCOUNT"
$NewPassword = "somePassword"


$computerNames = @(
    "someNameServer1",
    "someNameServer2"
)

$serverSession = New-CimSession -ComputerName $computerNames -Credential $sessionCredentials

$tasks = Get-ScheduledTask -CimSession $serverSession | Where-Object { $_.Principal.UserId -eq $taskDomainUsername }

foreach($task in $tasks) {
    echo updating $task
    $specificSession = $serverSession | Where-Object { $_.ComputerName -eq $task.PSComputerName}
    $taskFullName = $task.TaskPath+$task.TaskName
    Set-ScheduledTask -CimSession $specificSession -TaskName $taskFullName -User $taskDomainUsername -Password $NewPassword

}
```